# How to get the row data with max value field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I just started to learn MySQL.
How can I get max reg_count row data in the following data?

> ```
>     id  title   genreID  countryID  artistID  albumID  reg_count
> ------  ------  -------  ---------  --------  -------  ---------
>     16  hh            2          1         9       35         12
>     17  jj            2          1         9       36         34
>     18  kk            2          1         9       36         45
>     19  ll            2          1        10       33         56
>     20  zz            2          1        10       34         99
>     21  xx            2          1        10       34         52
> ```

I want to get the row data in which id is 18 and 20.  These row data have max reg_count value in each artistID field.
So I want to get the following row.

> ```
>     id  title   genreID  countryID  artistID  albumID  reg_count
> ------  ------  -------  ---------  --------  -------  ---------
>     18  kk            2          1         9       36         45
>     20  zz            2          1        10       34         99
> ```
>
> I tried with "GROUP BY". But I got unwanted results. How to get this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation function max( )
for get the max of an artist you could use

```
select artistID, max(reg_count)
from my_tbale  
group by  artistID
```

for get the related  rows you could use a subquery  with the previous query

```
seect m.* from my_table m
inner join  (
    select artistID, max(reg_count) max_count
    from my_tbale  
    group by  artistID
) t on t.artistID = m.artistID  
    AND t.max_count = m.reg_count
```